# Unable to access "from" property of a JIRA item

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I am trying to access the `from` property of an item while accessing JIRA. Python gives me a syntax error. What could be the problem?

```
for history in changelog.histories:
    for item in history.items:
        if (item.field.upper() == 'SPRINT'):
            try:
                if item.fromString:
                    sFromSprint = str(100) #python does not like item.from
                else:
                    sFromSprint = str(iZERO)
```

Error:

```
    iFromSprint = item.from
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

`from` is a reserved keyword in python

You can get the property using `getattr(item,'from')` instead.